# Connect from UWP App to Analysis Services

Tags: .net, service, uwp, analysis

I want to connect my UWP App (Min Version: Windows 10 Fall Creators Update 16299) to Microsoft Analyses Services 2017. In .NET Standard I can use a Reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll to do that. Since this is a .NET Standard dll I cannot use it in UWP. How do I proceed ?

Comment: You can use [.NET standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/) if your min target version is 16299. What is the error?

Comment: The error is: "A reference to "C:\...\AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll" could not be added. The project targets .NETCore while the file reference targets ".NETFramework". This is not a supported scenario.

Comment: Which nuget package you have used?